# Send a signal to USB using C#

Tags: c#, arduino, iot

My idea is to set off ligth in my room using the signal from laptop. 
I have already googled some experiments, but found no useful information about how this can be implemented.
I think that the technology should be the same as the plug-n-play devices (LED lamps, etc) uses.
How can we control USB external devices through USB port using programming languages.

Comment: That all differs depending on the device. Do you have any device in particular in mind?

Comment: @Chris, I have Arduino Uno.

Comment: Ah, didn't see the tag there. The Uno should show up as a virtual com port. So serial comms is the way to go: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Serial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Arduino boards have one or more serial ports, most (all?) have a usb-to-serial converter on board, so they'll show up as a virtual com port when connected.

On the Arduino side: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Serial

On the C# side: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx